# Multiple-characters filter / analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, character, stemming

Example

```
quatro
quattro
quatttro
...
quatttttttttttttttttttttttttro
```

Desired output

```
quatro
```

How to analyze (or filter..?) those terms, so elasticsearch analyzer will return only `quatro`?

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe not the best solution as i have to use _source and _source is pretty slow but it work (you could find a way to return 'abc' instead of 'a','b','c' i thinck ;))

Of course best solution should be to remove them at index time.
I dont thinck you could make an analyzer for this( because the order of your char is important)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "removeDup": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "def dup = new ArrayList(); def lastval = ''; def array_chars = params['_source']['yourfieldname'].toCharArray();for (int i=0; i< array_chars.length; i++){if(array_chars[i] != lastval) {lastval = array_chars[i];dup.add(lastval);}} return dup.toString();"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thx. I can't use scripts, so best way will be remove duplicate characters onserver side before putting them to index